# Sequence contains no elements. Enumerate windows tasks

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get all tasks using [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) , 
and have an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
>       in System.Linq.Enumerable.Last [TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source)

in line

> task_list.Last()["xml"] = task.Definition.RegistrationInfo.Description

```
public string GetAllTask()
{
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> task_list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    TaskService ts = new TaskService();
    TaskFolder fld = ts.GetFolder("WS");

    foreach (Task task in fld.Tasks)
    {
        task_list.Last()["xml"] = task.Definition.RegistrationInfo.Description;
    }

    var ser_task_list = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(task_list);

    return ser_task_list.ToString();
}
```

Comment: task_list is empty so error thrown before getting last element check if any element is in list using ``.Any()``

Comment: Like this:  ``if(task_list.Any()) { task_list.Last()["xml"] = task.Definition.RegistrationInfo.Description; }``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialisize `task_list` but add no items to it. Then you try to get the last item of the list inside the `foreach` loop but there is no item that's why you get this exception.

You can use `LastOrDefault`to get `null` if tere is no last element, but I think more that you need to add at least one item to `task_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding anything to `task_list` at any point. Why do you expect `task_list.Last()` to succeed?

Your code should probably look like this:

```
public string GetAllTask()
{
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> task_list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    TaskService ts = new TaskService();
    TaskFolder fld = ts.GetFolder("WS");
    foreach (Task task in fld.Tasks)
    {
            task_list.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>());
            //[Populate your new Dictionary object here]
            task_list.Last()["xml"] = task.Definition.RegistrationInfo.Description;
    }
    var ser_task_list = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(task_list);
    return ser_task_list.ToString();
}
```